# Converting a string to an Array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays

How can I convert a string into an array?

The values are passed as a string:

```
Dim strInput as string  
strInput = "Tom, John, Jason, Mike"
```

My error message is: `Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Array'`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Use [System.String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):**

```
Dim source As String = "Tom, John, Jason, Mike"
Dim stringSeparators() As String = {","}
Dim result() As String
result = source.Split(stringSeparators, _ 
                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

**Or use [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split.aspx)**

```
Dim source As String  = "Tom, John, Jason, Mike"
Dim result() As String = Split(source, ",")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use split().  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

strInput.Split(New String() {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)